# standalone rcp application, access secured EJBs, glassfish

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, eclipse-rcp, glassfish-3

I want to access EJBs with security.. 
I am developing an `eclipse rcp` application and I want to connect to a `glassfish 3.1.1` server that has some `EJB`s secured and I want to connect to that `EJB`s using `Java EE 6 security`

I found something like this:

```
ProgrammaticLogin pm = new ProgrammaticLogin();
pm.login(usernameText.getText(), passwordText.getText());

Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "com.sun.enterprise.naming");
props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.state", "com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl");
// optional. Defaults to localhost. Only needed if web server is running on a different host than the appserver
props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost");
// optional. Defaults to 3700. Only needed if target orb port is not 3700.
props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");

try
{
    Context ctx = new InitialContext(props);
}
catch (NamingException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I included all `jar`s from glassfish appclient.jar `glassfish3/glassfish/bin/package-appclient`

Example errors:

```
SEVERE: SEC9050: Programmatic login failed
com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException:  javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No LoginModules configured for default
at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver$9.run(LoginContextDriver.java:889)
...
```

Do you know how to securely login to `EJB`s using any method for a desktop application?

My references:

1. [Java EE 6 tutorial - security](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbwj.html)
2. [Java-Tips: accessing a secure EJB from a client](http://www.java-tips.org/java-ee-tips/enterprise-java-beans/accessing-a-secure-enterprise-bean-from-a-java-client-or-through-java-web-start-techn.html)

If you know the answer.. can you, please, provide me examples?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I know its old but your issue is, code is looking for "default" in `login.conf` file, There could be many specified here, if you do not specify, code try to find an entry with "default" some thing like as follow.
`deafult {
 com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.FileLoginModule required;
};` But your configuration does not have this entry which will be used to authenticate user. In standalone you also need to add `System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", authFile);` to help your code to locate config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try making the pm.login call *after* context initialization.

I know this question is old, but I stumbled across it after encountering the same error, and would have appreciated a solution.

I had code comparable to the following:

```
ProgrammaticLogin pm = new ProgrammaticLogin();
pm.login(username, pass, "file", true);
container = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(properties);
```

Simply re-ordering it as below solved the problem:

```
container = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(properties);
ProgrammaticLogin pm = new ProgrammaticLogin();
pm.login(username, pass, "file", true);
```

The idea being, at least as I understand my case, that the server/my connection to the server hadn't yet been initialized, and thus was unable to handle the login.

Comment: Hi Jonathat. thank you! I will try this. I accepted your answer because I think this is what I was missing.. it makes sense :)
I tried this a long time ago :P thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your client application is missing some dependent jars.

It appears that class you are missing is in: appserv-rt.jar

Now that jar might not be distributed with Eclipse.  Have checked to see if there is a Glassfish-client library?

Comment: I did but the gf client.jar is not the right one with programatic login... I know I am missing jars.. But so you know all the jars a standalone app need?

Comment: well.. appserv-rt.jar is not the problem.. I included all jars but I still can not connect to `EJB`s using `Java EE 6 security`